# Is Media Foundation supported on Windows 2012 64 bit server?

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio, lame

Is Media Foundation supported on Windows 2012 64 bit server? We can not have Windows 7 or Windows 8 as the server and that's the reason we are opting for Windows 2012 server.

As NAudio 1.7 is released now, we would like to utilize the new functionality with Media Foundation.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can install the Media Foundation components on Windows Server 2012.

Use the `Add Roles and Features` wizard from the Server Manager.  Skip through to `Features` and select `Media Foundation`.

Comment: Hi @Corey, I have a small problem with NAudio Media Foundation. I want to have Media Foundation Reader to be read from stream unlike file path. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: NAudio doesn't currently support it.  You'll have to implement that yourself if you need it.

Comment: Hi @Corey, I have issue with MFT while reading ogg file format. I have installed vorbis codec(64 bit) on my windows server 2012(64 bit), hoping that conversion will work, but there is no use. I not able understand why it is not possible to convert ogg file to mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using Windows Server 2008 R2 you can Add Features from Server Manager and then Select "Desktop Experience"

Comment: It better would be a comment!