# Improving EC2 ping times from home

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, steam, hamachi

I've been trying to run a gaming machine in EC2 following the excellent blog post by Larry Land [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839785/is-media-foundation-supported-on-windows-2012-64-bit-server).  The problem I have is latency from my home to my nearest AWS region.  I get a ping of around 35ms, and I'm looking to improve on that.  Is there anything I can do?  I'm using Steam n-home streaming over a Hamachi VPN, on Windows Server 2012.

My internet connection is roughly 120Mbps down and 35Mbps up, and there's nothing I can do to improve on that sadly.

Comment: _'not SO appropriate'_ - absolutely. [So] is for programming questions. Ask on [su]

Comment: OK thanks, I've moved it over to superuser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/909201/improving-ec2-ping-times-from-home)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the nearest region geographically isn't the one with the lowest latency. This is due to routing agreements that sometimes result in non-optimal routes.

A common example, is with Eastern Australia and Singapore. Routes often go to the US and or Japan before finally going back to Singapore.

Besides this, you should not be using wifi on your local network, depending how noisy the environment is, this can result in dropped packets that need to be retransmitted and increase the overall latency.

Routers can have an effect on this too, but unless its heavily loaded, its probably not adding much latency.

You may want to do some research with traceroute to see how each data center performs and where the slow spots are.