# Confusion with emgu.cv x86 folder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, emgucv

I developed an c# application using emgucv for face detection. According to emgucv documents folder "x86" or "x64" (depending on platform for which application is running) are need to be kept parallel to executing exe. So i did accordingly and run the project, application works just fine on my machine.

If I release this c# application along with all the dependent dlls and "x86" folder and copied to an windows 7 machine, after executing the application i get error `Unable to load DLL 'cvextern' : The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

**This is what i tried to solve the error:**
 I copied all the DLLs from folder "x86" to executing folder (i.e outside to x86 folder) and now application runs without any error.

So I am in confusion whether to keep x86 folder in executing folder or content of x86 folder. As per my observation both are working but what is recommended?

Comment: same problem is mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955105/emgucv-cvextern-system-dllnotfoundexception/36526333#36526333

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `cvextern.dll` file is located in the following folder:

> project_folder\bin\x86\Debug\x86
>   project_folder\bin\x86\Debug\x64

The same goes for the x64 version:

> project_folder\bin\x64\Debug\x64
>   project_folder\bin\x64\Debug\x64

The folder can also contain other files, e.g. `opencv_ffmpeg310.dll`. The `Emgu.CV.World.dll` and similar DLLs are located in the Debug/Release folder (one folder up).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of EmguCV you are using, I am using 3.2 so everything is built for x64. When I distribute my application, I create a x64 folder in the folder where the exe lives. In this x64 folder I put ALL of the DLLs from the EmguCV distribution. On my machine EmguCV lives in:
D:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop_x64-cuda-tbb-ipp-icc 3.2.0.2682

So from the bin\x64 folder I copy everything to where the application exe is.

Doug

Comment: EmguCV dropped support to x86? There is no more bin\x86 folder.