# EmguCV - Resolving Visual C++ Dependency in Mono/Xamarin - Mac OSX

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, emgucv, xamarin.mac

I have a project that is using old version of EmguCV.
In windows,it requires Visual C++ Redistributable for proper functioning.The Library throws some exception when its missing.I'm porting the same application for MacOSX using Mono.
I was wondering how this issue can be addressed in OSX?

Reference Question

[EmguCV cvextern System.DllNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955105/emgucv-cvextern-system-dllnotfoundexception)

Please advice.

Comment: You can compile the native macOS dylib from source (it is GPL unless you have a commercial license, then they supply the prebuilt library)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your reply.I have already referenced Emgu CV DLL in my c# project that uses GTK for UI.This Emgu depends on several other opencv and other DLLs which I copy to the bin folder(in windows).In addition to this I need visual studio 2015 dependency installed as mentioned in the question.I don't understand how I can use the .dylib to solve this problem.Please advice.

Comment: The VC 2015 runtime redistributable dependencies are Windows only **native** dlls, the EmguCV is a CIL wrapper for native libraries and those libraries are platform dependent and must be compiled for each platform. (those *opencv and other native DLLs* would also need to an macOS-based, not the Windows versions)

Comment: You can get `opencv` for macOS via `homebrew`, not sure about the version you need since you said you are using an old version of EmguCV, you would need to see if there is a brew recipe for the version that you need. I went once through this before, but the client ended up buying a commercial license since they decided to distribute the app and were not going to open source their app.

Comment: I just got lucky and got a precompiled version of EmguCv for OSX.It has all the necessary .dylib files too.The thing is I do not want to include system.drawing package as it can significantly delay the start up of the application (Takes long time to build the font cache).It seems Emgu.Cv uses system.drawing internally and cannot function without a system.drawing reference.Too Bad :( .Am I right ?

Comment: @SushiHangover I just got lucky and got a precompiled version of EmguCv for OSX.It has all the necessary .dylib files too.The thing is I do not want to include system.drawing package as it can significantly delay the start up of the application (Takes long time to build the font cache).It seems Emgu.Cv uses system.drawing internally and cannot function without a system.drawing reference.Too Bad :( .Am I right ?