# '' Unable to load DLL 'mfplat.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, naudio, naudio-framework

Here I used the below code for converting a wav formatted audio file for removing unwanted noise and better quality. This code works great in local host.. but while code run in IIS server, I got an error like:

> Unable to load DLL 'mfplat.dll':  The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

and I am using naudio codec for audio conversion. Anyone find solution for it, plz help me to sort it out..

```
 static void ConversionTest( string _outfilename, string _infilename )
    {
        try
        {
            using( var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(_infilename) )
            {
                // Create a wave format for 16-bit pcm at 8000 samples per second.
                int channels = reader.WaveFormat.Channels;
                int rate = 8000;
                int rawsize = 2;
                int blockalign = rawsize * channels; // this is the size of one sample.
                int bytespersecond = rate * blockalign;
                var midformat =
                    WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat( WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm,
                                                   rate,
                                                   channels,
                                                   bytespersecond,
                                                   blockalign,
                                                   rawsize * 8 );

                // And a conversion stream to turn input into 16-bit PCM.
                var midstream = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, midformat);
                //var midstream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(midformat, reader);

                // The output stream is our custom stream.
                var outstream = new PcmToALawConversionStream(midstream);


                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(_outfilename, outstream);
            }
        }
        catch( Exception _ex )
        {
        }
    }

    }
```

And here's the class that converts 16-bit PCM into A-Law or u-Law. At the end are specializations for A-Law or u-Law:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Encodes 16-bit PCM input into A- or u-Law, presenting the output
    /// as an IWaveProvider.
    /// </summary>
    public class PcmToG711ConversionStream : IWaveProvider
    {
        /// <summary>Gets the local a-law or u-law format.</summary>
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return waveFormat; } }

        /// <summary>Returns <paramref name="count"/> encoded bytes.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Note that <paramref name="count"/> is raw bytes.  It doesn't consider
        /// channel counts, etc.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="buffer">The output buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The starting position in the output buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of bytes to read.</param>
        /// <returns>The total number of bytes encoded into <paramref name="buffer"/>.</returns>
        public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            // We'll need a source buffer, twice the size of 'count'.
            int shortcount = count*2;
            byte [] rawsource = new byte [shortcount];
            int sourcecount = Provider.Read(rawsource, 0, shortcount);
            int bytecount = sourcecount / 2;
            for( int index = 0; index < bytecount; ++index )
            {
                short source = BitConverter.ToInt16(rawsource, index*2);
                buffer[offset+index] = Encode(source);
            }
            return bytecount;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes and A-Law or u-Law "WaveStream".  The source stream
        /// must be 16-bit PCM!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_encoding">ALaw or MuLaw only.</param>
        /// <param name="_sourcestream">The input PCM stream.</param>
        public PcmToG711ConversionStream( WaveFormatEncoding _encoding,
                                          IWaveProvider _provider )
        {
            Provider = _provider;
            WaveFormat sourceformat = Provider.WaveFormat;
            if( (sourceformat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm) &&
                (sourceformat.BitsPerSample != 16) )
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Input must be 16-bit PCM.  Try using a conversion stream.");
            }

            if( _encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.ALaw )
            {
                Encode = this.EncodeALaw;
                waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat( _provider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                                                          _provider.WaveFormat.Channels) ;

            }
            else if( _encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.MuLaw )
            {
                Encode = this.EncodeMuLaw;
                waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat( _provider.WaveFormat.SampleRate,
                                                           _provider.WaveFormat.Channels) ;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Encoding must be A-Law or u-Law");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>The a-law or u-law encoder delegate.</summary>
        EncodeHandler Encode;
        /// <summary>a-law or u-law wave format.</summary>
        WaveFormat waveFormat;
        /// <summary>The input stream.</summary>
        IWaveProvider Provider;

        /// <summary>A-Law or u-Law encoder delegate.</summary>
        /// <param name="_sample">The 16-bit PCM sample to encode.</param>
        /// <returns>The encoded value.</returns>
        delegate byte EncodeHandler( short _sample );

        byte EncodeALaw( short _sample )
        {
            return ALawEncoder.LinearToALawSample(_sample);
        }
        byte EncodeMuLaw( short _sample )
        {
            return MuLawEncoder.LinearToMuLawSample(_sample);
        }
    }


    public class PcmToALawConversionStream : PcmToG711ConversionStream
    {
        public PcmToALawConversionStream( IWaveProvider _provider )
          : base(WaveFormatEncoding.ALaw, _provider)
        {
        }
    }

    public class PcmToMuLawConversionStream : PcmToG711ConversionStream
    {
        public PcmToMuLawConversionStream( IWaveProvider _provider )
          : base(WaveFormatEncoding.MuLaw, _provider)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Media Foundation is an optional feature on Windows Server editions, so you need to install it. Some instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19848275/7532)

Comment: health I installed Media Foundation on Windows Server but still same error is showing.

Comment: try also installing "Desktop experience"

Answer (score 0):

Had this error when trying to open the "stream what you hear" (swyh) app from Windows 10 N. Fixed the error by installing the Media Feature Pack. See [Microsoft Media Feature Pack activation instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions-c1c6fffa-d052-8338-7a79-a4bb980a700a).